# How to create instance of a class (without extending it perse) but override a method using Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

Say we have a class like this:

```
interface I {
  method1?:() => void
}

class A implements I {
  method1?:() => void
}
```

or maybe:

```
abstract class A implements I {
  abstract method1?:() => void
}
```

I want to allow a user to create an instance A, but override `method1`.
The only way I know how to do that, is something like this:

```
class A implements I {
  constructor(v: I){
     if(v.method1){
       this.method1 = v.method1;  // override it with user-provided one
     }
   }
  method1?:() => void
}
```

which then looks like this:

```
const x = new A({
   method1(){...}
})
```

which is really not so bad, just requires extra code on the devs part in the implementation, which could be error-prone especially with many (and changing) methods.

it there someway to do this without using the abstract keyword and doign:

```
const x = new (class extends A(){
    method1(){}
})()
```

looking for potential alternatives, however, the one immediately above does seem to do the trick, just quite ugly (and it's hard to remember the syntax).

Comment: You want the user to be able to instantiate `A` and pass in a function to replace `method1`? Am I understanding that correctly? I want to ask why just doing something like `const x = new A({method1() { console.log('HELLO') }});` isn't enough, but I must clearly be misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: [This approach](https://tsplay.dev/mLrJKw) is close to what you have at the bottom, but I'm not sure why it's preferable to create an anonymous single-use class constructor to just having a non-`abstract` `A` that takes a constructor argument.  In any case, does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer, if not what am I missing?

Comment: I just don't see why this shouldnt be a standard feature in TS - we are still sticking to the same type (same exact signatures), simply overriding (or implementing) a method.

Comment: @NkemdiAnyiam with what you said the user (you and I) have to write code in the constructor to manually assign that method - it can be inconsistent and error-prone - better done at the language leve

Comment: It’s not a standard feature of TS because it’s not a standard feature of JS. If you want to ask that question it should be directed at TC39 (e.g., proposed as an Ecmascript feature) and not at TypeScript. Does that address the question? Did you mean to tag this with JavaScript instead or in addition?

Comment: @jcalz not true, totally standard and most critical part of JS is patching objects with arbitrary new properties, or reassigning properties on an object

Comment: The feature you’re talking about already exists in JS?  Can you demonstrate?  I’d be happy to retract my statement if you can show me your proposed syntax already working in pure JavaScript.

Comment: yes it just like: const f = {}; f.foo = () => ‘bar’ … its still f but with foo method

Comment: Okay, then you can do that with TS for class instances as well... see [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NaZZBm).  Does *that* meet your needs? If so I'll write it up, otherwise, what am I still missing?

Comment: @jcalz I will upvote your answer, but it's not really what I am looking for, I updated your playground link, check it out, thanks.

Comment: Try this link:  [our little playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLIN4ChnILYRgAWA9gCYCMA-AFzIAUAlMgLwB8yAbicGVgL5YsCADZwAzuOQBBZMDwAHERALgp6bLgLFy1JnW68A3AKEISIcWGQAPVshAQA7jKYmbAOm2lK9mAFcQBDBgCwZmTWRzSxJlDxESAHN6ACIiCBEElMYTQSwAenzkYjgwAHIpEGAkABpkACN-a3QnOHBikmQyTuJgcRohAqLeqXEAT3A4O26ISpJrCBs+6zHCAeirW3tHF2kmSK1CHwp9wX4TIeKiPvw4AGtZuWtozggqt+s2smQYKGA3sgiMYdZAKCRSCTIOBQRL9MwWTaIJAKMDiaQgWQsBhwOjSZjsTA4XAbWIQeJJehwHICC6FZD+cQoYDWETAB5XPoDJEQFFojH0HauRgYfBHXT7IT8fiMIRAA)

Comment: "this syntax does not exist yet", ah so it is *not* in fact a standard feature of JS.  Are we just talking past each other at this point?  What you are looking to do is not supported by JS, and thus is not supported by TS.  Do you understand and agree now?  Or is there still somehow a miscommunication?

Comment: @jcalz we seem to be talking past each other. We are on the same team. There is a lot of TS syntax that doesn't exist in JS as TS is a superset or whatnot. As long as there is a 1:1 clear way to transpile to JS, it can exist in TS.

Comment: No, it cannot.  Any suggestion to add non-JS syntax with JS output will be declined.  The TS github repo is full of declined requests for things like this; it just won't happen (e.g., see [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/587#issuecomment-379014712)).  Such TS-only runtime features that already exist come from a time before they were repeatedly burned by JS going in an incompatible direction (e.g., decorators, using define semantics for class fields). They're not going to do it anymore. Do all the pieces of the puzzle fit for you now?  And how shall we proceed here?